# Program skips parts of code

Tags: c, string, file, function

I have been having a constant problem in my c code, whenever I get an input and call a function, it will skip the first part of the function and do the next part.

EDIT: Problem has been solved, this code works perfectly normal.

use while((c= getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); after all input

```
void Fruit(void); 
void Fruit2(void);
void Chocolate(void);

int choice=0;
char fruit[32];
char fruit2[32];
char Choco[32];
int c;
int main()
{
printf("Which food do you prefer, 1=Fruit?, 2=Chocolate?");
scanf("%d",&choice);
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

                if(choice==1)
                {
                Fruit();
                }
                        else if(choice==2)
                        {
                        Chocolate();
                        }
                                    else
                                    {
                                    printf("Pick one");
                                    }
}


void Fruit(void)
{
     printf("Enter your favourite fruit?\n");
     gets(fruit);
     while((c= getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
     printf("What is your second most favourite fruit?\n\n");
     gets(fruit2);
     while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
     system("cls");
     printf("You like %s's and %s's ",fruit,fruit2);
     getch();
}

void Chocolate(void)
{
     printf("Enter your favourite chocolate bar\n\n");
     gets(Choco);
     while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
     system("cls");
     printf("You like %s",Choco);  
     getch();   
}
```

Comment: This is such a big FAQ.  Hint: Who will consume the newline after you select a value to begin with?

Comment: Did you hit `ENTER` after you choose `2`?

Comment: I would first try and fix "printf("You like %s");". What do you want to print here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `gets` in your function `Chocolate()` reads the `\n` character left behind by `scanf`. On pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, an extra character `\n` with input pass to the buffer. `scanf` doesn't read this character.  You need to consume that before the call of `gets`.

**Possible solution:** [What can I use to flush input?](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html)

---

I would like to suggest you not to use `gets`. It is now removed from C standard. Instead you can use `fgets`.

```
fgets(fruit, sizeof(fruit), stdin);
```

Comment: I am sure that you did't yet read the link provided in my answer.

Comment: The answer explained it already. I can't explain better than that. In simple `while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);` will consume your `\n` (and all other character in the input buffer).

Comment: Where do I put this?. after any \n?

Comment: Put this after each of your `scanf` and `gets`.

Comment: and I am guessing c is just a counter variable

Comment: No. You need to declare it as `int c;`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
    printf("You like %s's and %s's ");
```

You should have

```
     printf("You like %s's and %s's ", fruit, fruit2);
```

And similarly for the second print statement.

Comment: And `gets()` should not be used either.